# A Gradle based sub-project throws `Could not find or load main class worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain` during the build

Tags: java, gradle, classnotfoundexception

I have a Gradle based multi-project.

The issue is with one of the sub-projects. I have some tests there, but all code inside is commented out. Whenener I run "build" or even "assemble", which should not trigger a test phase, I get these errors during the test phase.
This started to happen just recently, I can't really pinpoint what might have started to cause this.

```sh
Could not write standard input to Gradle Test Executor 1.
java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:354)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.forwardContent(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.run(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Could not write standard input to Gradle Test Executor 2.
java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:354)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.forwardContent(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.run(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Could not write standard input to Gradle Test Executor 3.
java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:354)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.forwardContent(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.run(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Error: Could not find or load main class worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain
Error: Could not find or load main class worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain
Process 'Gradle Test Executor 2' finished with non-zero exit value 1
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'Gradle Test Executor 2' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:414)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.DefaultWorkerProcess.onProcessStop(DefaultWorkerProcess.java:141)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.DefaultWorkerProcess.access$000(DefaultWorkerProcess.java:42)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.DefaultWorkerProcess$1.executionFinished(DefaultWorkerProcess.java:94)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:245)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:141)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy142.executionFinished(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:221)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.finished(DefaultExecHandle.java:354)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.completed(ExecHandleRunner.java:110)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:84)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.run(CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Error: Could not find or load main class worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain
Process 'Gradle Test Executor 3' finished with non-zero exit value 1
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'Gradle Test Executor 3' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:414)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.DefaultWorkerProcess.onProcessStop(DefaultWorkerProcess.java:141)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.DefaultWorkerProcess.access$000(DefaultWorkerProcess.java:42)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.DefaultWorkerProcess$1.executionFinished(DefaultWorkerProcess.java:94)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:245)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:141)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy142.executionFinished(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:221)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.finished(DefaultExecHandle.java:354)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.completed(ExecHandleRunner.java:110)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:84)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.run(CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I can't really disclose my build files. Suffice to say, I use the spring gradle plugin and the dependency management plugin in root for all subprojects. Subproject build file contains just your regular dependencies and different tasks.

The root build.gradle contains this line:

```
wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '6.7.1'
}
```

I have JDK 11, Gradle `6.7.1.`, IDEA Ultimate `2020.3.3`.

I tried invalidating caches and restarting, cleaning before building, deleting `wrapper` folder and regenerating it using the `wrapper` task, `gradlew --stop`. Nothing helped so far. Other subprojects build fine, this one and root doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this by manually deleting eveything in `.caches` folder from Gradle user home directory.

Answer (score 5):

If gradle is running as a daemon, you need to empty the `.caches` directory *and* stop the daemon:

```
./gradle --stop
```

Or if using gradle wrapper:

```
./gradlew --stop
```

Comment: I build Java projects using Gradle on Mac and this answer was spot on! I had already removed my `.caches` without success.

Comment: Deleting without stopping will not work. The gradle daemon's memory cache must also be emptied. That's why both are required.

Comment: Not an answer. Read `I tried invalidating caches and restarting, cleaning before building, deleting wrapper folder and regenerating it using the wrapper task, gradlew --stop`. You are stating the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

This error (Could not find or load main class worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain) popped after I remove gradle cache (rm -fr  ~/.gradle/caches).

To fix it,if coomand ./gradle --stop not worked for me, I'm stopped graddle daemon by following command:

```
    ps -auxx|grep gradle| awk '{print $2 }'|xargs  kill
```

and run my build
My graddle version is 7.5.1